# How many of the request syntax parameters of ObjectSummary.get are necessary?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to get an object from an ObjectSummary using the ObjectSummary.get() function. However, the documentation does not explicitly state which parts of the request syntax are required. I would prefer not to use some parts (like IfMatch for example). Is it possible to only include some of the parameters?

Here is the syntax for your convenience:

```
response = object_summary.get(
    IfMatch='string',
    IfModifiedSince=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    IfNoneMatch='string',
    IfUnmodifiedSince=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    Range='string',
    ResponseCacheControl='string',
    ResponseContentDisposition='string',
    ResponseContentEncoding='string',
    ResponseContentLanguage='string',
    ResponseContentType='string',
    ResponseExpires=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    VersionId='string',
    SSECustomerAlgorithm='string',
    SSECustomerKey='string',
    RequestPayer='requester',
    PartNumber=123
)
```

from https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=s3.bucket.object#S3.ObjectSummary.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these parameters are required, unless you want the functionality that a given option provides -- for example, `IfModifiedSince` only returns the object if it was created/modified after the date you provide, and if you don't need that feature, don't use that option.

To simply "get an object" needs no options.